# Complicated mysql select

Tags: mysql, select, union

I have to select some data from the following table (a simplified version of it):

```
game    player   v1    v2
1       p1       2     3
1       p1       1     2
1       p2       5     3
1       p3       6     7
1       p3       2     1
2       p4       4     6
2       p2       2     1
2       p3       3     4
3       p1       4     9
3       p3       5     3
...
n       p3       3     4
n       p2       4     9
n       p3       5     3
```

When player p1 participates in a game (as it happens in game 1 and in game 3) I want to select the sum of all v2 observations for that player p1, by game.
When player p1 does not participate in a game (as in game 2 and game n), I want to select the sum of all v1 observations for all players in total, by game. I want the info for all players for all games, even though they do not participate in a particular game.

This is the final result I would like to find:

```
game    player    v
1       p1        5    (v2: 3+2)
1       p2        3    (v2: 3)
1       p3        8    (v2: 7+1)
1       p4        16   (v1: 2+1+5+6+2)
2       p1        9    (v1: 4+2+3)
2       p2        1    (v2: 1)
2       p3        4    (v2: 4)
2       p4        6    (v2: 6)
3       p1        9    (v2: 9)
3       p2        9    (v1: 4+5)
3       p3        3    (v2: 3)
3       p4        9    (v1: 4+5)
...
n       p1        12   (v1: 3+4+5)
n       p2        9    (v2: 9)
n       p3        3    (v2: 3)
n       p4        12   (v1: 3+4+5)
```

I would very much appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the 2 summaries use different group by conditions, I can only think of producing the sums in 2 subqueries left joined on a Cartesian product of games and players.

I assume that you have a players master data table as well that lists all players. I refer to it as `players` in the below example. I refer to your above table as `games`.

```
select
    t1.game,
    p.player,
    case
        when t2.player is null then t3.sumv1
        else t2.sumv2
    end as v
from (select distinct game from games) t1
inner join players p  --note the lack of join condition, I'm creating a Cartesian join
left join (select game, player, sum(v2) as sumv2 from games group by game, player) t2 on t1.game=t2.game and p.player=t2.player
left join (select game, sum(v1) as sumv1 from games group by game) t3 on t1.game=t3.game
```

Comment: Would you please explain it a little? What are "t1", "t2 and "t3"? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Aliases for subqueries. I use 3 subqueries as tables. I use the alias as if it was a table name.

Comment: ok, Ive tried it but it tells me that tables 'games' and 'players' do not exist.